# Deserialize nested xml nodes

Tags: php, symfony, jms-serializer

I've got an xml response from an api formatted as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<response success="true">
    <messages>
        <message type="WARNING" key="warning-unpublished-changes" values="" parentId="1">
            You have unpublished changes. Your changes will not be visible every where until it is published.</message>
    </messages>
    <output>
        <accounts>
            <account 
                id="1" 
                code="AssetsChild" 
                name="AssetsChild" 
                description="Total Assets Child"
                displayAs="CURRENCY"
                accountTypeCode="A"
                decimalPrecision="0"
                isAssumption="0"
                suppressZeroes="1"
                isDefaultRoot="1"
                shortName=""
                exchangeRateType="E"
                balanceType="DEBIT"
                formula=""
                isLinked="0"
                owningSheetId=""
                isSystem="0"
                isIntercompany="0"
                dataEntryType=""
                planBy="DELTA"
                timeRollup="LAST"
                timeWeightAcctId=""
                levelDimRollup="SUM"
                levelDimWeightAcctId=""
                rollupText=""
                startExpanded="1"
                hasSalaryDetail=""
                dataPrivacy="PRIVATE"
                isBreakbackEligible=""
                subType="CUMULATIVE"
                enableActuals="1"
                isGroup="0"
            />
        </accounts>
    </output>
</response>
```

I'd like to have it deserialized to a response object defined as:

```
class Response 
{
    protected $success;
    protected $messages;
    protected $accounts;
}
```

I've been able to successfully get the success value and message array using the config below. Is it possible to get the hydrate the accounts property with the list of account nodes?

```
Response\AccountResponse:
  xml_root_name: response
  properties:
    success:
      type: boolean
      xml_attribute: true
      xml_value: false

    messages:
      type: array<Entity\Message>
      xml_list:
        entry_name: message
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [SimpleXml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). specifically, use `simple_xml_load_string` to transform the string into a `SimpleXmlElement` the use the class methods to [navigate and extract the data](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).